# RSpec System spec can see factory data from model but not from view

Tags: rspec, ruby-on-rails-5, capybara, factory-bot

I have a system spec where I call 3 factories: 
Company has_many Shops has_many Shelves

In the code below, I place a debugger in both the spec and the ApplicationController.  When called from the spec, all factories are created as expected.  Then when I visit root_url, I cannot find the same records (or any records at all):
- Company.count returns 0
- Shop(find_by: id) returns nil (using the id of the shop created by the factory)

When I feed the same factories to seeds.rb and pull it up in my development environment, it renders the page & data correctly.

What could be causing the controllers to lose sight of the data in this spec?

The spec:

```
RSpec.describe "changing the current shop", type: :system do
  let(:company) { create(:company, name: "Test co") }
  let(:first_shop) { create(:shop_with_shelves, name: "seeded shop", company: company) }
  let(:last_shelf) { create(:standby_shelf, name: "Cool Shelf", shop: first_shop) }

it "displays the name of the current shop" do
  first_shop
  last_shelf
  # debugger here identifies all models created as expected
  visit root_path
end
```

the helper_method:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  helper_method :current_shop

  def current_shop
    # debugger here is unable to find any models Company.count = 0
    @current_shop ||= Company.first.current_shop
  end
end
```

in the view it is:

```
<%= current_shop.name %>
```

Failure/Error: @current_shop ||= Company.first.current_shop

```
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `current_shop' for nil:NilClass
```

If further testing I was able to see that system specs raise this error but feature specs do not as per below:

```
RSpec.describe "trying a system spec (this fails)", type: :system do
  let!(:company) { create(:company) }
  let!(:shop) { create(:shop, company: company, is_current: true) }
  it "gets to the shops page" do
    visit shops_path  
  end
end

RSpec.feature "trying a feature spec (this passes)", type: :feature do
  let!(:company) { create(:company) }
  let!(:shop) { create(:shop, company: company, is_current: true) }
  scenario "gets to the shops page" do
    visit shops_path  
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app and tests each have their own connection to the database. Assuming you are using a modern version of Rails (5.1+) you need to enable transactional tests and share the DB connection between the app and tests.

Comment: Thank you very much!At first, your suggestion to set config.use_transactional_fixtures: true and removing DatabaseCleaner from Rails helper did not clear this error.  It turned out that my spec's set-up data also was not correctly setting the current_shop which resulted in an identical error message.